# All or nothing / transaction statements with mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have the following two statements in a shell script:

```
 32 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root files -e "TRUNCATE path"
 33 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root files -e "
 34     LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/files.txt'
 35     INTO TABLE path
 36     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 37       (size, @d2, @d3, @d4, @d5, path)
 38     SET last_modified=str_to_date(CONCAT(@d2, ',', @d3, ',', @d4, ',', @d5), '%b,%d,%T,%Y');"
 39 }
```

How would I make it such that the commands starting on line 32 & 32 either both work or both fail (a transaction) ?

Comment: Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html):

```
BEGIN;
LOAD DATA INFILE ...;
SET ...;
COMMIT;
```

Unless you `COMMIT` the transaction, the database will not have those rows loaded or the columns updated.

As a note, [some operations cannot be "transactionalized" in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html), and this includes schema alterations as well as `TRUNCATE TABLE`. Some statements will force a commit regardless of your intentions, so be careful to avoid those when trying to create a transaction.

Comment: Thank you. Where would I start the transaction `BEGIN`, in the above two commands?

Comment: I think my example is very clear in that regard. Just prior to the `LOAD` operation.

Comment: And also, for a single statement (`LOAD INFILE`) wouldn't that, in and of itself, be transactional?

Comment: The `LOAD DATA` operation is *atomic* meaning it will add all rows or do nothing, but the `SET` operation could proceed independently.

Comment: Ah, I see now that your `SET` is a part of the `LOAD DATA` statement. If this is the case, which is unusual, then no transaction is required. Single statements are *usually* atomic. A transaction is for grouping together several otherwise atomic operations into a single atomic operation.

Comment: When using MyISAM a single statement is not necessarily atomic.

Comment: This is why people who value their data don't use MyISAM.